# Chosen not working in jquery dialog on reloading mvc partial

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, asp.net-mvc-partialview, jquery-chosen

I am loading two `MVC` Partial Views in jQuery UI dialog using following code for editing and adding a record:

```
$.get(url, function(data)
{
    dialogDiv.html(data);

            var $form = $(formid);

            $form.unbind();
            $form.data("validator", null);

            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(document);

            var dat = $form.data("unobtrusiveValidation");
            var opts = dat ? dat.options || '' : '';
            $form.validate(opts);


            //THIS FUNCTION ADDS PLUGINS ETC.
            runEditCreateStartScripts();

            dialogDiv.dialog('open');
});
```

Following is the function that wires-up `chosen` functionality.

```
function runEditCreateStartScripts(){
    $("select.chzn-select").chosen(
           { 
                no_results_text: "no match", 
                allow_single_deselect: true 
            });
}
```

Everything is perfect on first call. After opening one dialog say edit a few times everything is broken. There is only `hyperlink` available in place of chosen stuff. This also happens if I open one dialog say add and then second dialog. The bindings and other functionality from first one (add) is gone.

Any insights on why this might be happening?

Comment: Did you fix this? I have the same issue.

Comment: :( not @Esteban, I switched to good ol' jQuery AutoComplete

Answer (score 0):

The problem that caused my issue was that the modals I was loading via AJAX had inputs with the SAME ID as an input field that was already on the page (using Django that has generic ID generators for model fields). This caused collision between the two inputs when re-triggering .chosen() on the selector. When I made the ID fields unique, all worked as expected.
Hope this would have helped.